# How to return the output of program in a variable?

Tags: bash

Can any one tell me how to return the output of a program in a variable from command line?

```
var = ./a.out params
```

I am trying to get the output of program into a variable while running this from command line.

Comment: You could use e.g. [`popen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) or similar.

Comment: Do you want to get it into a *shell* variable, or a variable inside a C program? If in a shell, you should edit the tags of your question to reflect that, as it's not relevant what language the program you try to run is made in.

Comment: Joachim Pileborg -thanks for replying i want to get the variable value which is inside my c program into the command line variable i.e. "var" so that i can use it in other script  or program

Comment: If you print the value of that variable to STDOUT, you can capture it as described in the answers. If you want to extract the value of the variable from the program itself, you're going to need a debugger (e.g. `gdb`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complement the [answer from rasen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17418597/440558), to get the variable from inside your program to the external environment, you need to print it to `stdout`.

Using the syntax provided in the other answer simply takes all output from `stdout` and puts it in the shell environment variable `var`.

Answer (score 12):

To save the program output to `stdout` in variable in Unix shell, regardless of language program wrote in, you can use something like this

```
var=`./a.out params`
```

or this

```
var=$(./a.out params)
```

Remember not to put spaces before or after the `=` operator.

Comment: `$(./a.out)` has the advantage that you can nest as: `$(echo $(echo a) )`, while this is not possible with backticks

Comment: @mkp The language the program is made in is irrelevant, the assignments in this answer will put all that is written to `stdout` and put it in the environment variable `var`. If the program `a.out` is written in C, C++, Fortran or [Whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_%28programming_language%29) doesn't matter.

Comment: fine. it works for shell but what about perl it is not working there.

Comment: @mkp How is your Perl program generating the output being missed? `warn` or `die`?

Answer (score 1):

For output from multi-line command, you can do this:

```
output=$(
#multiline multiple commands
)
```

Or:

```
output=$(bash <<EOF
#multiline multiple commands
EOF
)
```

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
output="$(
./a.out params1
./a.out params2
echo etc..
)"
echo "$output"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass value from your program to shell via `stdout` (as was already said) or using `return` statement in your `main()` function from your C program. One-liner below illustrates both approaches:

`echo -e '#include <stdio.h>\n int main() { int a=11; int b=22; printf("%d\\n", a); return b; }' | gcc -xc -; w=$(./a.out); echo $?; echo $w`

Output:

`22`

`11`

Variable `a` is printed to `stdout` and variable `b` is returned in `main()`. Use `$?` in bash to get return value of most recent invoked command (in this case `./a.out`).

Comment: Why long echo? use cat with heredoc. Reduces confusion.

Comment: be aware that the exit status is an unsigned char, only returns values in the range 0 to 255